# what do these statements do?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am pondering over Request/Response methods of Scrapy.
Can somebody explain me what the below statements (the request part) actually do?:

```
    def get_url():
        url = raw_input('Enter the url of your website (including the http)')
        return url      
    start_urls = str(get_url())
    request= Request(start_urls)
    depth= request.meta['depth']
```

thanks

Comment: what exactly part don't you understand?

Comment: Have you seen http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html describe how start_urls and requests works together?

Comment: I am just wondering how I can use request() in combination of response(). I already checked the documentation, however, it's not clear to me how they work together

Comment: I don't know why you're calling a single URL `start_urls` in your code. Fortunately, the `Request` constructor doesn't want a `start_urls` list, it wants a single `url`, so your confusion cancels itself out.

Comment: Anyway, you usually don't want to generate a `Request` manually; they get generated by the `Spider`, and executed by the `Downloader`, giving you the `Response` objects directly. You sometimes have to _look_ at the `Request` object that goes with the `Response`, but you rarely have to create them. (And if you don't want to use a `Spider`, you probably don't want `scrapy` in the first place, just use `urllib2`/`urllib.request` or `requests`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "I am pondering over Request/Response methods of Scrapy", I think you're a little confused. `Request` and `Response` are classes, not methods.

And, while these classes of course do *have* methods, you don't ask about any of them, you just ask about one of the data attributes, `meta`.

Or, if you meant methods in the HTTP sense, well, a `Request` defaults to `GET`, but you can specify a different one with the `method=` argument; what else is there to know?

---

As the documentation for [`Request`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) says:

> A `Request` object represents an HTTP request, which is usually generated in the `Spider` and executed by the `Downloader`, and thus generating a `Response`.

In other words, you usually don't want to create one yourself. You give the `Spider` a list of URLs to start with, and it makes a `Request` for each URL on the list, and for each additional URL that it discovers while scraping.

You may sometimes need to *look at* the `Request` that goes with a `Response`. And you may occasionally need to *customize* the creation of `Request`s inside a complex `Spider`. But you will rarely need to craft them manually.

---

Meanwhile, you seem to have confused yourself with your naming. You've got a variable named `start_urls`, but it's not a list of URLs, it's a single URL. Which, if you actually used it as a `start_urls` in the normal way, would be treated as a list of single characters. But fortunately, you're not doing that; you're passing `start_urls` as the `url` argument to a `Request` object—and, since it happens to be just a single URL, your two confusions cancel out and you create a valid `Request` object.

You *could* then feed this `Request` object to a `Downloader` manually to get back a `Response` object. But there's no good reason to do that. If you want to download files manually instead of spidering them, just use the stdlib module [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)/[`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html), or a third-party library specifically designed for making manual downloading easy, like `requests`, not a spidering library.

---

Meanwhile, `depth= request.meta['depth']` will just return a `KeyError`. As the [`meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) docs explain, it's just a dictionary, which is empty for new `Request`s (unless you pass a `meta=` argument to the constructor, which you didn't), and:

> … is usually populated by different Scrapy components (extensions, middlewares, etc). So the data contained in this dict depends on the extensions you have enabled.

Since you haven't actually done anything with the `Request` after creation, it doesn't matter what extensions you have enabled; it's going to be empty.